# Avoiding dependency load order

Tags: ruby

I am writing a gem that looks as such:

`lib/my_gem.rb`:

```
require 'base64'
require 'ostruct'
require 'my_gem/utils.rb'
require 'my_gem/base.rb'
...
```

This has been fine until recently when the gem has added more functionality and the `lib/my_gem` directory has grown and grown.

Now, I'm having to be really careful to `require` my classes and modules in a very specific order because something in `utils` requires that `base.rb` be loaded first.  However, something in `base.rb` requires that `app.rb` be loaded before that.

So it turns into:

```
# require all standard libraries first
require 'base64'
require 'ostruct'
require 'my_gem/app.rb'  # be sure this is loaded before base!
require 'my_gem/base.rb' # be sure this is loaded before utils!
require 'my_gem/utils.rb' # be sure this is loaded before some other class!
```

I end up having a mess in this file all due to order of dependencies and I feel like there has to be a better way?

Comment: Why don't you require `app` in the `base` file if it depends on it?

Comment: @spickermann That's a reasonable question, I was trying to avoid having to `require 'app'`  in every file that depends on it.  Instead, I thought I could load it once and be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`Kernel#autoload`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload):

```
require 'base64'
require 'ostruct'
autoload :SomeModule, 'my_gem/app.rb'
autoload :AnotherModule, 'my_gem/base.rb'
autoload :SomeClass, 'my_gem/utils.rb'
```

The idea is that the source file is not loaded until the module/class defined in it is used, therefore you don't need to take care of the order of requiring source files.