# Reliable require of multiple files while respecting dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ubuntu, require

A `require`d Ruby file isn't finding a constant in another file in the same location, I suspect because of the order Ruby receives the files from the filesystem when using `Dir.each`. Different behaviour occurs on different machines/OSes. Is there a filesystem independent approach to using require?

In a rails app with rspec we have a spec_helper that requires everything under `spec/support`:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

In a module under that tree, Class A inherits from B, but on one machine (MacOS) `a.rb` is required before `b.rb` and dies because it can't find A. On another machine (Ubuntu) there is no problem. In fact I can't see a good reason why it **should** work on that machine.

```
#a.rb
puts "required A"
module MyModule
  class A < B
  end
end

#b.rb
puts "required B"
module MyModule
  class B
  end
end
```

When the specs run on the Mac, the `Dir.each {require}` causes the following output:

```
required A
/Users/me/myproject/spec/support/mymodule/a.rb:4:in `<module:MyModule>': uninitialized constant MyModule::B (NameError)
```

On the Ubuntu machine, we have

```
required B
required A
```

... no error. Since it's not alphabetic I guess that the Ruby on Ubuntu is getting the files on something other than filename, perhaps on timestamp or physical position on the disk. Both of these seem quite tenuous.

Comment: I just asked a very similar question the other day - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452227/avoiding-dependency-load-order

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly require b from inside a:

```
#a.rb
require 'b'
puts "required A"
module MyModule
  class A < B
  end
end
```

This will guarantee that b is always required before a, regardless of operating system load order.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an array, so you could just do this:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].sort.reverse.each { |f| require f }
```

Then ensure that dependencies are met in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

The gem [require_all](https://github.com/jarmo/require_all) appears to do what I want.